# Can't get my model out of wireframe mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, interface

I'm new to Blender and this site, so I apologize in advance if I'm not following any of the proper etiquette.  I'm no artist, but I'm trying to learn Blender so that I have some programmer art for me to work around in Unity.

I followed a tutorial for making a basic human model, I rigged it with rigify, and now I'm starting to export it following yet another tutorial.  The thing is, when I was trying to rig the model, I couldn't get the model to go transparent so that I could see the bones inside the model.  Eventually, I managed to get it into wireframe mode, but I can't get it back into solid mode.

It's probably just a display thing and not a property of the model itself, but I want to be sure.  I'm looking at the display options under the "Figure" pane in Blender, and none of the Display check boxes are checked, including the one that says "Wire".  I don't want to import a plain wireframe model into Unity, and even if that doesn't happen, this is functionality of Blender that I should really know anyway, so I'd appreciate any help that anyone has to offer.  If necessary, I can upload the .blend file, but I'm not sure what site people would prefer that I upload it to.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) The blendfile would be helpful.. http://www.pasteall.org/blend/ is a convenient blender-specific hosting service.

Comment: Did you try 'Z' to toggle wireframe/solid?

Comment: @gandalf3 [Here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29670) is the file.

Comment: @stacker Yes, but it seemed to be toggling the wireframe of the bones in the armature, even though I had the model selected and not the rig.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the *maximum draw type* of the mesh set to *wire* in *Object > Display*:

[image]

This setting limits the drawing of that object to a wireframe, regardless of other settings (it shouldn't have any affect on exporting).

Set it to textured or solid to see the faces.

Comment: Thanks.  That did it.  I'll get the hang of this thing some day.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but it’s still coming up in Google searches, so I thought I’d add another possible solution. I had this problem today. I found that it was because I previously used the View Align to object and then toggled between perspective and orthographic view (“5”). I then went about modelling, zooming, orbiting etc without taking it out of orthographic mode. Blender forces the model to be wireframe in this orthographic mode. Hitting the 5 key after I had orbited or paned the view didn’t take it out of orthographic mode, until I re-aligned the view again.

Had me stumped for a while too.

Cheers, hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

On Blender 3 and newer, you will have to do the following:

1. Select object that is being displayed in wireframe mode
2. Go to the panel on the right-hand side and click on the square icon (Object Properties)
3. Expand the option "Viewport Display"
4. Go down to the "Display As" drop-down menu
5. On this drop-down, the option "Wire" will be selected. You need to change it to "Textured"

[image]